# Terraform KMS_key_id invalid root key error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Below is my VPC, security group and KMS setting, I encounter the error:

> Terraform script has failed because of: Error:
> data.aws_kms_key.by_key_arn: : invalid or unknown key: kms_key_id,

I was given one KMS_key_id, so how to define the kms_key_id? should I use "data "aws_kms_key" "by_key_arn"?

is this a valid root key for my aws_vpc? eu-west-1 is my region,22***** is my aws account, 5367*-***** is my key id

```
 data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
   tags = {
    Name = "my_vpc"
    }
   }
 resource "aws_security_group" "a" {
    name   = "a"
    vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
    }
 data "aws_kms_key" "by_key_arn" {
     kms_key_id = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:22******:key/5367*-****-****-****-********"
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the ARN you're giving it doesn't exist. It's valid to use the key ID and not the full ARN - does that work?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the KMS key to encrypt something like an S3 bucket, you should be able to just do something like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "mybucket" {
  bucket = "mybucket"

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        kms_master_key_id = arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:22******:key/5367*-****-****-****-********"
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, if you are looking to use a key provided to use in multiple resources included besides using the key arn, you'd import it as such:

```
data "aws_kms_key" "by_key_arn" {
  key_id = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:22******:key/5367*-****-****-****-********"
}
```

Note the `key_id` parameter in the data block. You have `kms_key_id` which is not a valid parameter for that data block. Valid options for `key_id` are:

- Aliases: `alias/my-key`
- Key ID: `1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab`
- Alias ARN: `arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:111122223333:alias/my-key`
- Key ARN: `arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:111122223333:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab`

Refs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/kms_key

Comment: I use kms_key_id in ebs, also can't deploy, is there any thing wrong with below script: provider "aws" {
region = "eu-west-1"}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "test" {
    availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"
    size              = 40
    encrypted = "True"
    kms_key_id = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:22******:key/5367*-****-****-****-********"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "a" {
    name   = "a"
    vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}
}

Comment: logging part is below:   resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
    bucket = "my_insecure_bucket"
    acl    = "private"

    logging {
        target_bucket = "Bucket"
        target_prefix = "log/"
    }
}

data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
    tags = {
        Name = "my_vpc"
    }
}

Comment: There's nothing glaringly incorrect with the Terraform code. If you're still getting the original error you posted, it's because `kms_key_id` is not a valid option for the `aws_kms_key` data block. As I said in my answer, for the `aws_kms_key` data block you need to you `key_id`.